# Remove leading and trailing numbers from string, while leaving 2 numbers, using sed or awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a file containing lines like:

```
353451word2423157
anotherword
7412yetanother1
3262andherese123anotherline4359013
5342512354325324523andherese123anotherline45913
532453andherese123anotherline413
```

I'd like to strip most of the leading and tailing numbers (0-9), while still leaving 2 leading and trailing numbers in place, if any...

To clarify, for the list above, the expected output would be:

```
51word24
anotherword
12yetanother1
62andherese123anotherline43
23andherese123anotherline45
53andherese123anotherline41
```

Preferred tools would be sed or awk, but any other suggestions are welcome...

I've tried something like `sed 's/[0-9]\+$//' | sed 's/^[0-9]\+//'`, but obviously this strips all leading and trailing numbers...

Comment: By `Remove leading and trailing numbers from string` - by "string" do you mean from each whole line or from each string of non-digits? If the latter the answers you have so far would fail given input of `foo12345bar` (i.e. more than 4 digits in between 2 strings of non-digits) so you should include that in your sample input/output if it can occur. Actually, include that case either way to clarify your requirements for middle digits. Also include the case of a line that's ALL digits, e.g. `12345`, or state if that can't happen.

Comment: Each line contains just 1 string, and there are no lines that contain just numbers...

And, no... it's not for homework, I'm too old for that :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^[0-9]+([0-9]{2})|([0-9]{2})[0-9]+$/\1\2/g' file

51word24
anotherword
12yetanother1
62andherese123anotherline43
23andherese123anotherline45
53andherese123anotherline41
```

**Command Details:**

- `^[0-9]+([0-9]{2})`: Match 1+ digits at start if that is followed by 2 digits (captured in a group) and replace with 2 digits in group #1.
- `([0-9]{2})[0-9]+$`: Match 1+ digits at the end if that is preceded by 2 digits (captured in a group) and replace with 2 digits in group #2.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's/^\d+(?=\d{2})|(\d{2})\d+$/$1/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/vcvZ9z) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m4slHb/3).

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=\d{2})` - on the right, there must be two digits (not added to the match as the lookahead is a non-consuming pattern)
- `|` - or
- `(\d{2})` - two digits captured into Group 1 (`$1`)
- `\d+`  - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk that trims digits to a max of 2 on each side of a string:

```
awk '{  match($0, /^[0-9]*/); lh=RLENGTH
        s=substr($0, lh>2 ? lh-1 : 1)
        match(s, /[0-9]*$/); rh=RLENGTH
        print substr(s, 1, rh>2 ? length(s)-rh+2 : length(s))
}' file
```

Prints:

```
51word24
anotherword
12yetanother1
62andherese123anotherline43
23andherese123anotherline45
53andherese123anotherline41
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` `gensub()` function with parentheses in the regexp to mark the components and then specifying them in the replacement (here `"\\2\\3"`)

```
awk '{print gensub(/^([[:digit:]]*)([[:digit:]]{2})|([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]*)$/,"\\2\\3","g",$0)}' file
51word24
anotherword
12yetanother1
62andherese123anotherline43
23andherese123anotherline45
53andherese123anotherline41
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
353451word2423157
anotherword
7412yetanother1
3262andherese123anotherline4359013
5342512354325324523andherese123anotherline45913
532453andherese123anotherline413
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+|[^0-9]+";OFS=""}$1~/[0-9]+/{$1=substr($1,length($1)-1)}$NF~/[0-9]+/{$NF=substr($NF,1,2)}{print}' file.txt
```

output

```
51word24
anotherword
12yetanother1
62andherese123anotherline43
23andherese123anotherline45
53andherese123anotherline41
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU `AWK` to split into fields which consist solely of digits or solely of non-digits using `FPAT`. If 1st column (`$1`) consist of digits, I slice it to get 2 last characters. If last column (`$NF`) consist solely of digits, I slice it to get 2 first characters. Finally whole line is `print`ed using empty string as output field seperator (`OFS`).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*